# flutter app stuck on "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'..." forever

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

when i run the app, it gets stuck forever.

I've been working on this project for about 6 months, I have never had a problem with gradle

has anyone ever experienced something similar?

here is the output of my flutter doctor

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
\[√\] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.4, on Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.19044.2251\], locale en-CH)
Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...\[√\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
\[√\] Chrome - develop for the web
\[√\] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.19)
\[√\] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
\[√\] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2)
\[√\] VS Code (version 1.73.1)  
\[√\] Connected device (4 available)
\[√\] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

I also tried to do gradlew clean, but it gets stuck aswell

```
.\\gradlew clean
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 16 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :firebase_auth
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=true' is deprecated.
> It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> You will no longer be able to disable R8
> \<-------------\> 0% EXECUTING \[8m 32s\]
```

Comment: Is there any firewall on your network?

Comment: No, I am working on my domestic network. Nothing in my network configuration , neither on my computer before this bug appeared.

Comment: And I can still build on other projects , just this one who causes problems

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.